# Receiving Content-Type: text/vnd.wap.wml from Stack Overflow when logged out

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, header

My computer says it is going to download a file with no information or name, but the Content-Type is set as `text/vnd.wap.wml` from http://stackoverflow.com if I am logged out. Is anybody else having the same issue?

Comment: Same thing happened to me!

Comment: Hmmm, and then I logged in, and it stopped doing it.

Comment: Starts again if I log out.  Odd!

Comment: @jjnguy Ah, you seem to be right—I guess that's why I couldn't repro it. I've updated the question correspondingly.

Comment: what browsers and os guys

Comment: No repro. Can anyone provide more information?

Comment: @jjnguy, which browser are you using?

Comment: @You, chrome 10

Comment: Happened to me yesterday, also with Chrome. Though it was only for the homepage, navigating to any other page from the site was fine.

Comment: I saw it last night as well on Chrome and Firefox 4.  Couldn't get in.

Comment: @quentez @jzd are either of you behind a proxy?

Comment: Weird. Sounds like a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

This was an issue with down-level browsers requesting "text/vnd.wap.wml" via the "Accept" header. There is an IIS/ASP.NET behaviour where it tries to accomodate this (very poorly, IMO) - which is fine in principle.... unless that response happens to get cached as `[OutputCache]`. As a result, occasionally those results could get cached and fed to people who were expecting "text/html".

Fortunately, there was a fairly simple fix:

[Make IIS not render pages as WML. Ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261144/make-iis-not-render-pages-as-wml-ever/5909281#5909281)